# How to add a course in progress on your resume?

Tags: resume

I am studying in Smart Professional Management Information System (MIS).

How would I add this to my resume? This course will be over in four months.

Comment: 1) Open resume in word processor... 2) Edit resume... 3) ???? 4) Profit

Comment: Are you asking if/how you should put a "course in progress" on your resume?

Answer (score 4):

> **MIS**
>
> Month/Year of start - Month/Year of end

Believe me, the recruiter will see it is a course in progress with the dates.